# Linear Algebra Multiplicity Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable $n\times n$ matrix.  Show that if an eigenvalue $\lambda$ has multiplicity $n$, then $A=\lambda{}I$

Comment: Diagonalizable means $A=PDP^{-1}$. Now write the matrix $D$ in terms of $\lambda$ and do some matrix arithmetic.

Comment: If an $n\times n$ matrix has an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n$ then the resulting $n^\text{th}$ degree equation must be able to written as: $a(\lambda - \lambda_0)^n = 0$ where $\lambda = \lambda_0$.  Don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: for some given matrix, how do you know if "an eigenvalue $\lambda$ has multiplicity $n$" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q$ be an invertible matrix such that $D=Q^{-1}AQ,$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Observe that
\begin{align}
(\lambda-t)^n=\det(A-tI)=\det[Q^{-1}(A-tI)Q]=\det(D-tI)=\prod_{i=1}^n(D_{ii}-t),
\end{align}
it follows that $D_{ii}=\lambda$ for each $i$. Thus
$D=\lambda I$ and then $A=Q(\lambda I)Q^{-1}=\lambda I$.

Comment: Even shorter proof: $A$ only has one possible eigenvalue, namely $\lambda$. $D$ is the matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ along its diagonal, so $D=\lambda I$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman But it is inconspicuous when you say the diagonal entries of $D$ are eigenvalues of $A$.